# Crystal report Sum Formula with if condition

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a table with 4 column with following value in my database
Quantity    Amount      Type            SaleDate
2           1200        T-Shirt         01/01/2020
3           3000        Shoe            03/01/2020
1           2500        shoe            01/02/2020
5           900         T-Shirt         06/01/2020

I want to create a report in crystal report of total Quantity and amount of sale of shoe and T-Shirt from 01/01/2020 to 28/01/2020. Example: Here 01/01/2020 to 28/01/2020 my shoe sale Quantity is 4 and amount is 5500 and T-Shirt Quantity is 7 and amount is 2100. i want to show the value of quantity and sale amount in my report. How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

One option to create a Running Total and specify a condition.

A better option is to create a simple formula that returns the value if the condition is true and zero otherwise.  Then, simply total that